# Compare column against valid values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset, linq-to-objects

I have 2 datasets
ds1 and ds2
ds1 contains valid values used in ds2
for e.g.
ds1 contains subject table containing Maths, Science, History.
ds2 contains Student table
Student table contains Subject column.
ds2->Student->Subject values should be present in ds->subject table.

How to implement this type of validation in effective way.
I don't want to iterate through each row and column of student table.

e.g.
**Students Table**
*Name Subject*
Peter Maths
George Science
Joe IT
Roger History

**Subjects Table**
*Subject*
Maths
Science
Maths
History

Now I want to validate the data in Students Table against Subject table 
Check if the Subject is present in Subjects table or not.
Here I want row *Joe IT* since *IT* is not present in Subjects table it is invalid.

Similarly , I need to check Students table data with multiple tables like Subjects.

I want LINQ query.

Comment: Please create a clearer question. Give some examples and explain why you don't want to iterate through the rows/columns.

Comment: You can use Linq to query the DataTables, however depending on your scenario, iterating over the tables may certainly be effective. Need more info on what your trying to accomplish though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following query

```
var noSubject =
  ds.Student.AsEnumerable().Where(s => ds.Subject.Rows.Find(s.Subject) == null);
```